# One invocation at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

The function main works perfectly by itself, my issue is that the start and stop button is creating multiple instances of main. Logging resets after clicking start&stop twice logs 2 arrays. One with main[0] values, and another main[2]'s which is empty as it should be.

```
$('#Jquery w/e').click(function() {
  //some other side effects
  if (stopped) {
    start()
  } else {
    stop()
  }
})

function start() {
  //some more unrelated side effects
  main()
}

function stop() {
  //undo side effects
}

function main() {
  var resets = []
  $(unrelatedVariable).click(function() {
    resets.push("click#'s")
  })
}
```

Is it possible to clear a previously called function from memory and how?

Comment: You are creating a new click binding on the moreJQ each time main() is called.  Don't do that™

Comment: This is something i typed out in 30 seconds. '#moreJQ' is programmatically decided and chosen based on other input. Still a no no?

Comment: I cannot think of a rational case where attaching the exact same event handler to the exact same element multiple times, effectively duplicating process unnecessarily, is a good idea.  Case in point of potential issues due to doing so, your question, :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Should every `unrelatedVariable` element have it's own `resets` array? Should there only be one `resets` array for all elements?

Comment: different variables are pushed into resets depending on the button pressed, buttons are also being created throughout the program